# How to make an Eclipse builder program run a python script?

Tags: python, windows, eclipse, prebuild

I am in the process of developing a preprocessor in Python. Trying to have a builder run my Python script results in the following error:

[image]

I read somewhere, that the file needs to be a .exe. This is not convenient as I am trying to improve the script and would have to generate an .exe everytime I changed something.

This is the configuration of the builder program (project -> properties -> builders -> 'Preprocessor'):

[image]

Comment: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/common/handouts/introtopythonineclipse/

Comment: @sudobangbang I want to run a Python script as a prebuild event on my Java project. The script is at a different location.

Comment: Specify the path of the python executable in the location and put the path of the .py file in the Arguments.

Comment: did you solve it by any chance?
i can do it if i specify the path to the python.exe but it might be diffrent for other computers so i want it to use the PATH variable in windows to find it by itself.